# UIBarButtonItem not displayed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibarbuttonitem

I can't make my UIBarButtonItem to display. I simplified it as much as I could, but even this does not display the bar :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    UIBarButtonItem *supprBouton =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                   initWithTitle:@"Supprimer"
                                   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                   target:self
                                   action:@selector(supprimerDate:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = supprBouton;

    UIBarButtonItem *enregBouton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                                    initWithTitle:@"Enregistrer"
                                    style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                    target:self
                                    action:@selector(enregFichier:)];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = enregBouton;
    [enregBouton release];
    [supprBouton release];
}
```

One right button, one left, this should be displayed at least, no ? What can be wrong ?

Comment: Do you have a navigation Bar (navigation Controller) at all?

Comment: @Fabien Lebas: Are you sure that the data Navigation Controller is integrated?

Comment: If the problem is fixed, please add or accept an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Without more context, my best guess is that you have not yet set up a `UINavigationController`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a uinavigationcontroller to your view:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
UINavigationController *navCntrl1 = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc];
```

Comment: Thanks all ! You're certainly right because you 4 gave me the same answer ! Tommy, your code is not working because it says "Unused variable nacCntrl1". I'm in a UITableViewController, maybe this can be useful for you. I could not find any proper tutorial for editing / deleting a Table View... Thanks for your support !

Comment: well, yea. you need to push this nav controller later :)